# Why is my method not running in this while loop?

Tags: java, methods, while-loop

I'm new to learning Java and was asked to write a program that takes an integer as input (in this case 100 coins) and simulates a "slot machine" where each cost to play is one coin and after 35 plays the machine pays out 25 winnings. These winnings then need to be transferred to the variable holding the original input to simulate that the person was able to keep playing until they ran out of coins.

The issue I'm having right now is when I run my debugger, I'm noticing that the call to method "machineOne()' isn't happening and I'm stumped as to why right now.

I'm still working on this assignment so some things are missing but can anyone offer some guidance as to why my method won't run?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class VickieVegasCasino {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int coinsInJar = coinInput();
        
        while (coinsInJar > 0) {
            
            coinsInJar = coinsInJar + machineOne();
            
            --coinsInJar;
        
            machineOne();
        
        }
        
    }
    
    public static int coinInput() {
        
        System.out.println("Hi Vickie, how many quarters did you bring?");
        
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        int coinsEntered = scan.nextInt();
        
        return coinsEntered;
    }
    
    
    public static int machineOne() {
        
        int machineOnePlays = 0;
        
        int machineOneLoser = 0;
        
        if (machineOnePlays < 35) {
            
            ++machineOnePlays;
            
        } else { 
            
            System.out.println("Congrats! You just won $6.25 on machine one!");
            
            machineOnePlays = 0;
            
            int machineOneWinnings = 25;
            
            return machineOneWinnings;
            
        }
        
        return machineOneLoser;
        
    }

}
```

Comment: Too many problems... For instance since `int machineOnePlays = 0;` and that you never change its value `if (machineOnePlays < 35){ /*code1*/ } else { /*code2*/ }` can only execute `/*code1*/` as `0<35` making `else {..}` part dead code. Also `return machineOneLoser` can be rewritten as `return 0` since `int machineOneLoser = 0;` and you also never change `machineOneLoser` so it always holds 0.

Comment: I thought by having the `++machineOnePlays;` line within the if statement it would increase the value of machineOnePlays each time time it ran. When it hits 35 it was supposed to run the else statement which prints out the string information and resets the machineOnePlays counter to 0.

Comment: 1) `machineOnePlays` is a local variable because it is declared within the method `machineOne` - with each call it is reset to 0. 2) You call `machineOne()` twice and the second call is not assigned to any variable.

Answer (score 0):

I have created your Java program in IntelliJ and set a breakpoint. When I debugged your program, the breakpoint lets me enter the  **machineOne** method:

[image]

What Java IDE are you using. Where did you set your breakpoint.

From what i am seeing - the code works nicely in terms of calling **machineOne**.

PS - there are some logic errors (such as your variable machineOnePlays is reset to 0 each time machineOne is called) - but the point of this was to see if **machineOne** is being called - which it is.

Comment: I'm sorry, I worded this post poorly, still trying to wrap my head around this stuff. It calls the **machineOne()** method but when I'm running the debugger in Eclipse I'm not seeing it jump down to that portion of my code and run the statements I have inside the **machineOne()** method.

Comment: Set a break point at the 1st line in your machineOne method and run in Debug mode. You should get a line in debug mode as shown in my screen shot

Answer (score 0):

`call to method "machineOne()' isn't happening -` not true, it is indeed calling machineOne(), since `machineOneLoser` is always zero and `zero` is returned from `machineOne()` hence you feel `machineOne()` never called